# Undefined variable in PHP file

Tags: php

I am getting error *Undefined variable: con*  at line:

```
$filter_Result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

in this PHP file:

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/conexion.php'); 

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    echo "estoy filtrando";
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
    // search in all table columns
    // using concat mysql function
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tblusuario` WHERE CONCAT(`idUsuario`, `strEmail, `strNombre`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);

    $totalRows_DatosConsulta = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);

}
 else {

     echo "estoy sin filtrar";

     $query = "SELECT * FROM `tblusuario`";
     $search_result = filterTable( $query );

     $totalRows_DatosConsulta = mysqli_num_rows( $search_result );
}


function filterTable($query)
{
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    return $filter_Result;
}
?>
```

Here is file conexion.php, where variable $con is defined:

```
$hostname_con = "p:localhost";
$database_con = "ondemand";
$username_con = "root";
$password_con = "";
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname_con, $username_con, $password_con, $database_con);
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
```

I have checked if file conexion.php is found correctly, and it is loaded.

I am not able to find the reason for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it like this

```
function filterTable($query)
{
    global $con;
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    return $filter_Result;
}
```

or you can pass the `$con` as argument while calling the function.

```
   function filterTable($con, $query)
    {
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        return $filter_Result;
    }
```

It is due to scope of variable in PHP.

Comment: Using a global is the NASTY way of doing it

Comment: @RiggsFolly Added alternate solution too!

Comment: Thank yoy @HariLamichhane.

Comment: Its my pleasure :) Remember to read more about variable scopes so that it will help you later.

Answer (score 1):

```
function filterTable($con, $query)
{
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    return $filter_Result;
}
```